# I've got some error in rasa when I try to give the comment rasa shell

Tags: python-3.8, rasa

I'm making rasa chat bot for 2 weeks. I've cloned the code from github the cloned code was in older version rasa 1.8, so converted the code into rasa 2.0  but some error acquired in action.py file .I don't know what the error is please help me to sort it out
I've attached the image below please see to that and give me a solution.

[vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSTey.png)

[error which was acquired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g1iA.png)

Comment: For best results: post your code+errors/traces inline, with the appropriate formatting (3x` or leading 4x<space>)

Comment: We need more information too please. Like what else errors are you receiving, because I think there will be more than just the one error you are receiving. Also be sure to report this problem in Rasa Forums.

Comment: https://github.com/Nithin07-crypto/covid19-chatbot       there will be my code please see to that